# Error trying to use a C++ class inside Python 3

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm trying to use a class I declared and implemented on C++, inside Python.
Even though I successfully declare my class in a Python wrapper, when I try to use the class's functions or even when I try to create an instance of this class I get:

```
[andre@atlantis mcasta]$ python TimedInputWrapper.py
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here's my C++ file (input_timeout.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <string>

class TimedInput {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::string prompt, input_string;
    long int li_time_limit;
    std::chrono::seconds time_limit;
public:
    TimedInput(std::string prompt_str, long int time) : prompt{prompt_str}, li_time_limit{time} { }

    void read_string() {
        std::cin >> input_string;
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    std::string return_input() {
        std::cout << "Time limit for input = " << li_time_limit << " seconds!\n" << prompt << "\n";
        std::thread th(&TimedInput::read_string, this);

        std::mutex mtx;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        time_limit = (std::chrono::seconds) li_time_limit;

        while ((cv.wait_for(lck, time_limit) != std::cv_status::timeout) and (input_string.empty())) { }

        th.detach();
        return input_string;
    }
};

extern "C" {
    TimedInput* TimedInput_new(std::string prompt, long int time_limit) { return new TimedInput(prompt, time_limit); }
    void TimedInput_read_string(TimedInput* timed_input) { timed_input->read_string(); }
    std::string TimedInput_return_input(TimedInput* timed_input) { timed_input->return_input(); }
}
```

I created a shared library with these commands:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -pthread input_timeout.cpp -o input_timeout.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libTimedInput.so -o libTimedInput.so  input_timeout.o
```

And this is my Python Wrapper/test(TimedInputWrapper.py):

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libTimedInput.so')


class TimedInput(object):
    def __init__(self, prompt, time_limit):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.time_limit = time_limit
        self.obj = lib.TimedInput_new(self.prompt, self.time_limit)

    def read_string(self):
        lib.TimedInput_read_string(self.obj)

    def return_input(self):
        lib.TimedInput_return_input(self.obj)

prompt = ctypes.c_wchar_p("What's your name?")
time_limit = ctypes.c_long(10)

TimedInput(prompt, time_limit).return_input()
```

Comment: The locks looked wrong, so I was going to try calling those functions in c++, before worrying about python. However, the compiler has multiple issues with your code so I couldn't even do that.

Comment: I have never tried to use C++ methods in Python like in your example - I am not sure if it is correct approach. However, it seems that for your purpose `boost::python` or `pybind11` might work just fine.

Comment: `ctypes` does not understand `std::string`.  `TimedInput_new` should take a `const char*` instead and you should pass the string as a byte string from Python.  `ctypes` will have a problem with `return_input()` returning `std::string` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `ctypes` does not work with C++ types, such as `std::string`. However, `ctypes` does work with C language types, such as `const char*`.

See [Fundamental Data Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) in the Python `ctypes` documentation.